# How to set unity build scene path from command line

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a unity 3d project from command line only, without a companion build pipeline static method.

My attempts fail, unity complains about '' is an incorrect scene path. Can I not set the scene path from command line?

`"C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -batchmode -nographics -quit -projectPath "C:\unity-project" -buildWindowsPlayer "C:\unity-project\test.exe" "C:\unity-project\Assets\Scene_01.unity"`

Gives the error:

`Aborting batchmode due to failure:
'' is an incorrect path for a scene file. BuildPlayer expects paths relative to the project folder.`

I get the same error if I change directory to the project path and use `Assets\Scene_01.unity`, and many variation of this.

**EDIT**
Values tried for the scene

`Scene_01.unity`

`./Scene_01.unity`

`.\Scene_01.unity`

`Assets/Scene_01.unity`

`Assets\Scene_01.unity`

`./Assets/Scene_01.unity`

`.\Assets\Scene_01.unity`

`/Assets/Scene_01.unity`

`\Assets\Scene_01.unity`

Note that no where that I've been able to find does it say you can even specify the scene(s) on command line. I feel unity doesn't want me doing this.

Comment: this command does not produce anything for me. Any idea where I could find logs ?

Comment: also: What is the option for android builds "-buildAndroidPlayer" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define the scene name(s) to be built from the command line. Unity stores the scenes that will be built in the ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset  Your only way around this is to make sure that the build settings are correct with the scenes you want before using the command line, or to create your own custom static function that you can pass in your scene file name(s) and start the builder that way.

Comment: For anyone wondering _how_ to "make sure the build settings are correct with the scenes you want before using the command line", manually run a build in the editor by going to `File -> Build Settings...` and add the scenes you want and click Build.

Comment: Before running the build, your ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset file will have an empty value for `m_Scenes`. After running the build, you will see something next to `m_Scenes` that includes something like `path: Assets/Scene_01.unity`, and at that point my build worked from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs by various situations,

1. The user delete the scene
2. The user rename the scene
3. The user moves the scene from one directory to another using windows / mac file manager (not inside the unity)

The solution for this problem is simple.

**Just remove the scenes from the player settings build list and add once again.**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

> BuildPlayer expects paths relative to the project folder.

This error seems pretty straightforward. Seems like you have to use *path relative to the project folder*, which is, in your case, is `\Assets\Scene_01.unity`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately this did not work (same error). I would like to point out that paths beginning with a slash are absolute paths by convention. So had this worked, I wouldn't have considered it "straightforward".

Comment: Have you tried `Assets\Scene_01.unity`, `Assets/Scene_01.unity`, `./Assets/Scene_01.unity` and `Scene_01.unity`?

Comment: I've updated my question - but yes, I've tried all those variations. I'm going to repost this question on the unity forums.